# Getting an error as "No such file or directory" in perl

Tags: perl

Here is my code, I am passing the files with subroutine. From subroutine i am not able to open the file. and it is throwing an error a

> "Couldn't open
>   inputFiles/Fundamental.FinancialLineItem.FinancialLineItem.SelfSourcedPublic.SHE.1.2017-01-11-2259.Full.txt
>   : No such file or directory at Practice_Dubugg.pl line 40."

```
    use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Std;
use FileHandle;

my %opts;
my $optstr = "i:o:";
getopts("$optstr", \%opts);
if($opts{i} eq '' || $opts{o} eq '' )
{
        print "usage: perl TextCompare_Fund.pl <-i INPUTFILE> <-o MAPREDUCE OUTPUTFILE>\n";
        die 1;
}
my $inputFilesPath=$opts{i};
my $outputFilesPath=$opts{o};
my @ifiles=`ls $inputFilesPath`;
my @ofiles=`ls $outputFilesPath`;
foreach my $ifile (@ifiles)
{
    my $ifile_substr=substr("$ifile",0,-25);
    foreach my $ofile (@ofiles)
    {
        my $ofile_substr=substr("$ofile",0,-21);
        my $result=$ifile_substr cmp $ofile_substr;
        if($result eq 0)
        {
            print "$result\n";
            #print "$ifile\n";
            compare($ifile,$ofile)
        }
    }
}
sub compare
{
    my $afile="$_[0]";
    my $bfile="$_[1]";
    my $path1="$inputFilesPath/$afile";
    my $path2="$outputFilesPath/$bfile";
    #open FILE, "<", $path1 or die "$!:$path1";
    open my $infile, "<", $path1 or die "Couldn't open $path1: $!";
    my %a_lines;
    my %b_lines;
    my $count1=0;
    while (my $line = <$infile>) 
    {
        chomp $line;
        $a_lines{$line} = undef;
        $count1=$count1+1;
    }
    print"File1 records count : $count1\n";
    close $infile;
    my $file=substr("$afile",0,-25);
    my $OUTPUT = "/hadoop/user/m6034690/Kishore/$file.comparision_result";
    open my $outfile, "<", $path2 or die "Couldn't open $path2: $!";
    open (OUTPUT, ">$OUTPUT") or die "Cannot open $OUTPUT \n";

    my $count=0;
    my $count2=0;
    while (my $line = <$outfile>) 
    {
        chomp $line;
        $b_lines{$line} = undef;
        $count2=$count2+1;
        next if exists $a_lines{$line};
        $count=$count+1;
        print OUTPUT "$line \t===> The Line which is selected from file2/arg2 is mismatching/not available in file1\n";
    }   
    print "File2 records count : $count2\n";
    print "Total mismatching/unavailable records in file1 : $count\n";
    close $outfile;
    close OUTPUT;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have a relative path that doesn't fit

Comment: What OS are you running, I can see it is unix based, but is it Redhat, Suse, etc? the error is pretty specific, so how are you passing the path?

Comment: I ran the script and it is not giving me errors because I am passing it the correct paths. Show how you are you running the script? send full command as you run it.

Comment: I am running this script in unix machine only. Even I am also passing correct paths, but still the file is not able to open.

Comment: sub count
{
        $path="$_[0]/$_[1]";

        #$file="$_[0]";
        #my $filepath = "$path/$file";
        open FILE, "<", $path or die "$!:$path";
        while (my $line = <FILE>)
        {
                chomp $line;
                $a_lines{$line} = undef;
                $count1=$count1+1;
        }
        print "$count1"
}
$file="Fundamental.FinancialLineItem.FinancialLineItem.SelfSourcedPublic.SHE.1.2017-01-11-2259.Full.txt";
$path="/hadoop/user/m6034690/Kishore/inputFiles/";
count($path,$file) ==>I have written this small script to verify the path.

Comment: I have written this small script to verify whether the path is correctly taking or not. With this script I can able to do open a file but I am not understanding why the file is not opening with my main script.

Comment: Here is the execution                                      m6034690@cmp111zbk:~/Kishore> perl Practice_Dubugg.pl -i /hadoop/user/m6034690/Kishore/inputFiles -o /hadoop/user/m6034690/Kishore/outputFiles
0
Couldn't open /hadoop/user/m6034690/Kishore/inputFiles/Fundamental.FinancialLineItem.FinancialLineItem.SelfSourcedPublic.SHE.1.2017-01-11-2259.Full.txt
: No such file or directory at Practice_Dubugg.pl line 40.

Comment: ok, but you are not specifying a filename, just inputFiles and outputFiles directories?

Comment: I am taking the filename from subroutine by passing as an arguments

Comment: I am giving the paths as directories and from there i am finding the matched files from for loop and passing those two files to sub routine

Comment: Don't use `ls` from Perl. `my @ifiles = glob "$inputFilesPath/*"` is the better way of doing this and also fixes your problem.

Comment: Thanks Borodin. This worked fine for me. I need one more help. Right now the above script is able to compare around 9GB to 10GBfiles. But I wanted to compare with very big files like more than 40GB.When I try to run my script with these big file my script has been killed automatically. can you give any suggestion how to improve the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try by adding the following lines after te below comment.

```
my $afile="$_[0]";
my $bfile="$_[1]";
my $path1="$inputFilesPath/$afile";
my $path2="$outputFilesPath/$bfile";

#comment, add the below chomps right under the above portion.
chomp $path1;
chomp $path2;
```

My test works as the path is now properly formatted.

my result:

```
File1 records count : 1
File2 records count : 1
Total mismatching/unavailable records in file1 : 1
```

It took a while to figure this issue out, but it was a bit confusing as the script says usage is `-i INPUTFILE` and `-o OUTPUTFILE`

This tells me I should add a file path and not path to folders, but regardless, issue should be resolved.

Edit:
an even better option, We should add the chomp where the `ls` occurs.

```
chomp( my @ifiles=`ls $inputFilesPath` );
chomp( my @ofiles=`ls $outputFilesPath` );
```

Comment: Wow...great Gerry. It worked fine for me now. Thanks a lot. I couldn't find that issue.

Comment: pleasure man. it is simple really. the `ls` is creating each resukt with a `\n` character and chomp is removing it.

Comment: Hey Gerry, I need one more help. I am comparing two very big files like the size is 40GB each. While running my script it has been killed automatically. Can you help how to improve the performance to run such big files with my script.

Comment: @nmkishore, I think you should consider `sort` and read both files simultaneously and comparing them on the fly.

Comment: Right now the above script is able to compare around 9GB to 10GBfiles. But I wanted to compare with very big files like more than 50GB. Even sorting may take more time to sort the both files. Is there any alternative. Please suggest.

Comment: I think the biggest problem here is that you are pushing results to hash which will use memory. so by sorting you will be able to do something more simple and reading line by line from both files matching each. this means you will never have more than 2 strings in memory.

Comment: Can you provide an example code snippet so that I can modify my script accordingly.

Comment: Hi Gerry, even while sorting also the entire file will be taken into memory, in that case also the script fails right?. Can you explain how to sort the huge file(50GB).

Comment: post a new question and I will answer there. I will keep an eye on the new posts now.